# CRT mode for AES

Tags: c#, aes

I needed to implement CRT mode for AES and coded following codes. But I am not an expert so I want to know experts comments that is it right or I made some mistake that will cause security problem.

I tried to minimize code to be easier to read, so I deleted some methods and add some comment where they used.

This class may change size of entered data. I know it is not good idea to do this in coder/decoder class but base on program conditions it was far easier to do this there.

If you need more detail please comment. and I will be thankful if you recommend notes to make it safer and better.

Note: I asked this question [there](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160051/is-it-good-implement-for-aes-ctr-mode) and they recommend me to ask this question here.

**Edit: thanks for your great answer and comments, but I am more concern about security. Is this code Secure?**

```
public class Rij : IDisposable
        {
            private const int defaultMaxRijendaelNumber = 2;
            private const int blockSize = 128;
            private const int blockSizeInBytes = 16;
            public enum Type { Coder, Decoder };
            private Type instanceType = Type.Coder;
            private int maxRijendaelNumber = defaultMaxRijendaelNumber;
            private long allLength = 0;
            private long doneLength = 0;
            private byte[] counter = new byte[blockSizeInBytes];
            private RijndaelManaged rijndael = null;
            private ICryptoTransform crypto = null;
            private bool disposed = false;
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            public Rij(Type type, string pass, byte[] salt, byte[] counterStartValue, long size)
            {
                int iteration = 50000;
                byte[] passWordSalt = (byte[])salt.Clone();
                byte[] passArray = ConvertToByteArray(pass);
                byte[] passWord = new byte[0];
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcPass = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passArray, passWordSalt, iteration);
                FillWithZero(ref passArray);
                passWord = rfcPass.GetBytes(16);
                counter = (byte[])counterStartValue.Clone();
                instanceType = type;

                rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
                rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                rijndael.Key = passWord;
                rijndael.BlockSize = blockSize;
                rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                FillWithZero(ref passWord);
                allLength = size;

                if (type == Type.Coder) { crypto = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(); }
                else { crypto = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(); }
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            public void RijCoder(ref byte[] bufferToCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = bufferToCode;

                    //make size dividable by 16
                    if (doneLength + buffer.Length == allLength && allLength % blockSizeInBytes != 0)
                    {
                        int addableLength = Convert.ToInt32(blockSizeInBytes - (allLength % blockSizeInBytes));
                        byte[] bufferHelper = new byte[buffer.Length + addableLength];
                        byte[] fakeData = new byte[addableLength];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, bufferHelper, 0, buffer.Length);
                        buffer = bufferHelper;
                    }

                    //divide length for useing multi task
                    int[] partsSize = DivideSize(buffer.Length);

                    Task[] tasks = new Task[partsSize.Length];
                    List<byte[]> counters = new List<byte[]>();//counter(iv) for each task
                    int[] startIndexes = new int[partsSize.Length];//start index in buffer for each task

                    int startIndex = 0;
                    int oldStartIndex = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < partsSize.Length; i++)
                    {
                        startIndexes[i] = startIndex;

                        //set counter
                        counters.Add((byte[])counter.Clone());

                        //update startIndex,counter 
                        oldStartIndex = startIndex;
                        startIndex += partsSize[i];

                        //update counter
                        increaseCounter(counter, (startIndex - oldStartIndex) / blockSizeInBytes);
                    }

                    //run
                    var parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < partsSize.Length; m++)
                        {
                            int index = m;

                            tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                CodePart(buffer, counters[index], startIndexes[index], partsSize[index]);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    //wait
                    try
                    {
                        parentTask.Wait();
                        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException)
                    { throw new Exception("exeption in encoding tasks"); }

                    bufferToCode = buffer;
                    doneLength += buffer.Length;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void CodePart(byte[] buffer, byte[] counterForPart, int startByte, int length)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (length == 0) { return; }

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += blockSizeInBytes)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < blockSizeInBytes; j++)
                        { buffer[startByte + i + j] ^= counterForPart[j];  }

                        IncreaseCounterByOne(counterForPart);
                    }

                    Array.Copy(crypto.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, startByte, length), 0, buffer, startByte, length);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void IncreaseCounterByOne(byte[] bytes)
            {
                for (int i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (bytes[i] == byte.MaxValue)
                    { bytes[i] = 0; }
                    else
                    { bytes[i]++; break; }
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposed) { return; }

                rijndael.Dispose();
                disposed = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have several typos: CRT instead of CTR, Rijen instead of Rijn, useing instead of using, dividable instead of divisible, exeption instead of exception. This means you should probably get an IDE that does some spell checking. As long as no one has posted an answer, you may still correct these in your question.

Comment: Lack separation of concerns. For example, you're mixing password based key derivation with your implementation of CTR mode in the same class.

Answer (score 4):

Things like this

> ```
> catch (AggregateException)
> {
>   throw new Exception("exeption in encoding tasks");
> }
> ```

or that

> ```
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>   throw new Exception(ex.Message);
> }
> ```

are so bad that I wish you never have to debug such code. This is the worst you can write. You loose all the information about what went wrong. The entire stack trace, line numbers, method names and in the first case all inner exceptions. If you don't handle an execption don't do anything. Let it *bubble* and let the user take care of it.